# How do I convert a react render method content into pug, instead of standard component way

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pug

While I know how to write a render method's return in pug, I am stuck in a place where I have to pass a component as an attribute's value of some another component.

Inside my react render method, I am returning the following code :

```
<PDFDownloadLink  document={<PdfDocument data={meetingDetails} />}
          fileName="meetingName.pdf"
          style={{
            textDecoration: "none",
            padding: "10px",
            color: "#4a4a4a",
            backgroundColor: "#f2f2f2",
            border: "1px solid #4a4a4a"
          }}>
        
      {({ blob, url, loading, error }) =>
        loading ? 'Loading document...' : 'Download'
      }

      </PDFDownloadLink>
```

where I am importing PdfDocument as well as PDFDownloadLink components.

Now I have to write the same thing in pug, which I did as below...

1.

```
PDFDownloadLink(document={<PdfDocument data={meetingDetails} />}
          fileName="meetingName.pdf"
          style={{
            textDecoration: "none",
            padding: "10px",
            color: "#4a4a4a",
            backgroundColor: "#f2f2f2",
            border: "1px solid #4a4a4a"
          }} )
```

2. 

```
PDFDownloadLink(document={PdfDocument(data={meetingDetails} ) }
          fileName="meetingName.pdf"
          style={{
            textDecoration: "none",
            padding: "10px",
            color: "#4a4a4a",
            backgroundColor: "#f2f2f2",
            border: "1px solid #4a4a4a"
          }})
```

Both do not seem to work. Any sort of help / guidance would be helpful.